# How to prevent duplicate invoice no in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-8

I am working on an invoicing application using Laravel. I generate the Invoice no within the model. Many invoices created corrected. A few days before we check the application, we got two duplicate invoices with the same invoice no, but the customer and items are different (created_at time is the same).

**Invoice Model**

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $maxnos = Invoice::Where('branch_id', $model->branch_id)
            ->max('invoice_nos');
        $memnos = str_pad((int) $maxnos + 1, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $model->invoice_nos = $memnos;
    });
}
```

How can I prevent a duplicate invoice no in the model?

Comment: 1 St database column set unique then add  try catch of duplicate the generate new no

Comment: Every branch has unique values. so we don't set invoice_no as unique @KamleshPaul

Comment: then you should add branch name as prefix to make all `unique`

Comment: You might find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxCGsz2Drgg) helpful.